# How to get related object in angular JS template?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest

It should be noted that I'm very new to Angular.

I have the following JSON I get from Django Rest Framework:

api/movie/1

```
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Mr & Mrs Smith",
        "actors": [
            1,
            2,
        ]
    }
```

api/actor/1

```
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Angelina Jolie",
    }
```

api/actor/2

```
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Brad Pitt",
    }
```

I made a movie detail page following the Angular tutorial, using $resource.
This is the movie-detail.component.js

```
angular.
  module('movieDetail').
  component('movieDetail', {
    templateUrl: 'static/partials/movie-detail/movie-detail.template.html',
    controller: [ '$routeParams', 'Movie', 
      function MovieDetailController($routeParams, Movie) {
        var self = this;
          self.movie= Movie.get({movieId: $routeParams.movieId})
      }
    ]
  });
```

In the movie HTML template, I have access to the "actors" id via "$ctrl.movie.actors". But I can't figure out if there is a way to use this id to ask the server for the 'actor' object. Something like :
Actor.get({id}) to incorporate them in the movie details template.

TL;DR
What I can do now :

```
Actors:
    <ul>
       <ling-repeat="actor in $ctrl.movie.actors"> {{actor}} </li>
    </ul>
```

result:

> Actors
>
> - 1
> - 2

And I want something along the lines of :

```
Actors:
    <ul>
       <ling-repeat="actor in $ctrl.movie.actors"> {{actor.name}} </li>
    </ul>
```

result:

> Actors
>
> - Angelina Jolie
> - Brad Pitt

How can this be achieved ?

Thank you for any replies!

Answer (score 0):

First of All you are using Angularjs 2 and Angularjs 2 is way different then Angularjs 1.*.

In this case its more javascript object manipulation rather Angularjs tricks

you can try below ways to achieve this

**option1:**

if you are able to edit your rest call in Django, change your code to return the movie and actor details in one js like this

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Mr & Mrs Smith",
    "actors": [
        1: {"id": 1,"name": "Angelina Jolie"},
        2: {"id": 1,"name": "Angelina Jolie"},
    ]
 }
```

And try to ng-repeat for you actor object under movie. or you can separate both the calls as your requirement.

**option2:**

You need to do a lazy loading at the time of loading. once your movie object is loaded, you need to call actor rest url to get all the actor object required and append them in the existing object if you are unable to make a single rest call.then in the template you can show actor detail as above.

Comment: About option 1: I can nest serializers in Django to achieve a similar JSON output but I think it will bloat the class with useless information on other calls. I think it would be better to ask the server for this data only when it's needed.

Option2 seems exactly like what I want to do. Can you show an example of how this can be achieved?

Comment: Also, As far as I know I use Angular 1.5.7

Comment: I did not explor angular 1.5. Might the 1.5 have the component option. I think its my bad. For the implementation of 2nd option, Make one http call to get all movie and once its done make separate call in a loop to get all actors in background. while the actors are loading, show the loading symbol under actor field in view.